# how do I refer to a dynamic created ngModel angular

Tags: angular

I have  in a `*ngFor` loop and have made it a NgModel by giving it a dynamic name, how do I refer to the same NgModel component for reading it's value ?

Here's my code

```
<tr *ngFor="let advise of selectedAdviseList | sortAdvises">
    <td>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="close_{{advise.ticker}}">
                50% <-"Show the real value of the number range slider"
            </label>
            <input 
                type="range" 
                class="form-control" 
                name="close_{{advise.ticker}}" 
                id="close_{{advise.ticker}}">
        </div>
    </td>
    <!-- ... more code -->
</tr>
```

Comment: Where are you specifying ngModel?

Comment: Is this template code, a part of a form? If so, you can get the value of the form.

Comment: Normally you have an array of models models:Model[]=[]. Using *ngFor="let ..;let i=index you can use [(ngModel)]="modles[i].ticker". Anyway, perhafs you want to take a look to reactiveForms and FormArray https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#dynamic-controls-using-form-arrays

Comment: Thanx Eliseo - I think I will have to move on the path you have suggested

Answer (score 0):

You can easily refer to your input dynamically by making use of the `index`.

Refer to the below example:-

```
<p *ngFor="let advise of [1,2,3,4,5]; let i = index">
    <td>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="close_{{advise.ticker}}">
                50% <-"Show the real value of the number range slider"
            </label>
            <input 
                type="range" 
                class="form-control" 
                name="close_{{advise.ticker}}" 
                id="close_{{advise.ticker}}"
                [(ngModel)]="ranges[i]">
        </div>
        <div>Value: {{ranges[i]}}</div>
    </td>
</p>
```

[Please refer to the working Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mudsyi?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)